# Can I separate data on JBOD

Tags: linux, jbod

My initial feeling is that it probably can't be done, but somebody may be wiser. This is the situation: I have a NAS from D-Link with two different sized disks, set up as JBOD; I would like to push all the data to one disk and then transfer the disks to a different system - is this possible? As far as I have been able to figure out, there is no way to log on to the NAS and do stuff there.

Answer (score 0):

No. You will need an intermediary storage of you want to re-use the disks.

I presume you are aware of data reliability rates on JBOD arrays? External and independent NAS USB backup is a must.